# Nexus OSS 2 - Repository Targets

Tags: nexus

I am trying to setup a Nexus OSS 2 Repository with *Repository Targets*.

Reading the documentation, it implies I should be able to set a repository target with pattern "^/a/b/c/.*" and grant the appropriate CRUD permissions (specifically Read) and assign it to a user or role.

I assumed that if I grand this permission that a user can use the nexus UI to browse to each node of /a/b/c and download anything at or below "c".

However, to get this to work I need to grant all of the following patterns:

- ^/
- ^/a/
- ^/a/b/
- ^/a/b/c/
- ^/a/b/c/.*

Is this correct or a bug?

I assume that this has to do with the REST API to expand the tree nodes... accessing the a.b.c|xyz.jar directly with maven probably would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, you need to adjust the regular expression to allow browsing, see here:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464568-Browse-storage-doesn-t-work-for-users-with-restricted-read-access-

Comment: Thanks rseddon.  I ended up going another way because this going to be way too much configuration / maintenance down the road...but I appreciate the answer! :)